# mmenu Disables Tabbing Between Form Elements

Tags: javascript, forms, mmenu

mmenu, when opened, is preventing the ability to use the rest of the page as usual, specifically relating to tabbing between form elements and allowing you to press a key on an input element or textarea and have the key repeat (i.e. aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa).

Apparently this is something that is built into mmenu but it's a real problem since we are using it in an always open state for desktops and need this functionality.

I do not want to modify any behavior of media elements with a max-width of 899px (mobile devices), only the desktop (min-width 900px), which is the first portion of the script beginning with if (mql.matches).

My current "fire the mmenu" script is:

```html
        <script>
function mediaqueryresponse(x) {
if (mql.matches)
             {
            document.addEventListener(
                "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                   new Mmenu( "#navmenu", {
                       "openingInterval": 0,
                       "transitionDuration": 0,
                       wrappers: ["bootstrap"],
                       "extensions": [
                          "position-front",
                          "fx-panels-none",
                          "theme-dark"
                       ],
                       "offCanvas":
                          {
                          "blockUI": false,
                          "moveBackground": true
                          },
                       "sidebar": 
                          {
                          "expanded":
                              {
                              "use": true
                              }
                          },
                       "navbar": 
                          {
                                "title": "INTRANET"
                          },
                       "navbars": [
                          {
                             "position": "top",
                             "content": [
                                "prev",
                                "title"
                             ],
                          },
                          {
                             "position": "bottom",
                             "content": [
                                "<a class='fa fa-envelope' href='mailto:webmaster@example.com'></a>",
                                "<a class='fa fa-twitter' href='https://www.twitter.com/example'></a>",
                                "<a class='fa fa-facebook' href='fb://profile/6515649878645135'></a>"
                             ]
                          }
                       ]
                    });
                }
            );
}
else
             {
            document.addEventListener(
                "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                    new Mmenu( "#navmenu", {
                       wrappers: ["bootstrap"],
                       "extensions": [
                          "position-front",
                          "pagedim-black",
                          "theme-dark"
                       ],
                       "navbar": 
                          {
                                "title": "INTRANET"
                          },
                       "navbars": [
                          {
                             "position": "top",
                             "content": [
                                "prev",
                                "title"
                             ],
                          },
                          {
                             "position": "bottom",
                             "content": [
                                "<a class='fa fa-envelope' href='mailto:webmaster@example.com'></a>",
                                "<a class='fa fa-twitter' href='https://www.twitter.com/example'></a>",
                                "<a class='fa fa-facebook' href='fb://profile/6515649878645135'></a>"
                             ]
                          }
                       ]
                    });
                }
            );
}
}
var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 900px) and (orientation:landscape)")
mediaqueryresponse(mql) // call listener function explicitly at run time
mql.addListener(mediaqueryresponse) // attach listener function to listen in on state changes
        </script>
```

Comment: This is also discussed here. Maybe it helps?
https://github.com/FrDH/mmenu-js/issues/73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have solved it for me:

After your menu code, which will look somewhat like this:

```
new Mmenu(document.querySelector("#menu"), {
 [...]
}
```

you add:

```
document.body.removeEventListener('keydown', document.body.mmEventKeydownTabguard[0])
```

This is the solution posted here:

https://github.com/FrDH/mmenu-js/issues/86

Comment: Yes, that worked and I can now tab between form elements on a page. I still cannot hold a key down and have it repeat but the tabbing thing was the main issue. Thanks!

Comment: Have not tried it, but what happens when you set keyboardNavigation to false? https://mmenujs.com/docs/addons/keyboard-navigation.html